# Change global td attributes based on device detection using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I thought this would be easy to do, but I'm not finding an answer.  I have this stylesheet which sets the global font-size of all td's.

```
td {        
    font-size: 20px;  
}
```

I would like to detect the device type in javascript and change the value of td globally, so font sizes are larger on mobile devices. Is there a way to set the global td programatically? I have the device detection working.

Comment: you can use % instead of px or media querys

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the right font-size on every mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16387400/getting-the-right-font-size-on-every-mobile-device)

Comment: you can use `vw` for device width or `vh` for device height. Example: `font-size: 3vh`.  [CSS_Values_and_Units#Dimensions - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Values_and_Units#Dimensions)

Comment: Ooo I didn't know about the vw and vh! I may just go that route, but is there a way in javascript to change td values globally, say like if I clicked on a button?

Comment: @Jonathan Yes use the .css method in javascript

Comment: @xmaster I have used that, but it only updates what is currently visible, so if I refresh the content it inherits the original td values.

Answer (score 1):

there are tons of ways to achieve this. Personally I love to use [media querys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

Here is an example:

```css
  td {
     font-size: 20px;
     }

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  td {
     font-size: 10px;
  }
  }
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="warning">
      <td>Area</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here you can see it changes the `font-size` when you click full page. You can also use `vw` this will take a % of the width of the screen. But then you have to add a viewport

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/sy8rf657/2/)

Comment: That does work though I clarified by question by adding "in Javascript" in the title. One of the key points I was looking for was: "Is there a way to set the global td programatically?" in Javascript